# Call specific Component in Ember

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I've got a Component "comments"

```
<div class="comments">
    <ul>
        {{#each comment in comments}}
            ...
    </ul>
</div>
```

which is present multiple times in the HTML:

```
Product A:
{{comments}}

Product B:
{{comments}}

etc.
```

If I set "comments" all Components render the comments. How can I tell Ember to set the Comments for a specific Product only? e.g. on headline click and Ajax Load.

JS Bin: http://jsbin.com/wafacojenahe/2/edit

Comment: I don't really understand what you're saying here, I'm having a hard time understanding the context.  Would you please create an example, there are great templates here: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/ember.js/info

Comment: I've posted a JSBin in the my Question. So you can see, that the comments are rendered under both Products, but each Component should only load the Comments of it's corresponding Product (e.g. onClick)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues with your code.

You didn't have any hierarchy (or sets of) in the data. This has a basic structure in place:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return [
      {
        'name': 'Product A',
        'comments': [
          'Lorem ipsum',
          'dolor sit amet'
        ]
      },
      {
        'name': 'Product B',
        'comments': [
          "Another comment"
        ]
      }
    ];
  }
});
```

And the other issue is that components always need to be passed all data in.

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    {{#each product in model}}
      <h1>{{product.name}}</h1>
      {{comments-list model=product.comments}}
    {{/each}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="components/comments-list">
    <ul>
      {{#each model}}
        <li>{{this}}</li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </script>
```

JS Bin: http://jsbin.com/wafacojenahe/3/

Comment: Thank you for your help. My App is build similar to your JSBin, but the Comments should load on Click via Ajax (I've edited my Question a little bit).Do I have to populate the Comments Array in each Product? e.g. Product B Comments Array is empty -> load Comments via Ajax -> push Comments into Comments Array of Prodct B? How does Ember know, which Product to fill with Comments and how do I?

Comment: That changes your question a fair bit, and instead you should post a new question showing what you have so far and what you are struggling with (and ideally accept the given answer, if that did answer the question). If you're not using ember-data yet, consider trying it at least first ... it'll help with the ajax calls.

Comment: Ok, so I try ember-data and if it won't work, I will ask again ;) Thank you!